# Reactjs, How to use moment.js is between

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have this array:

["2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08"]

And this code is suposed to seak if a date is between the start/end but is not working:

```
array.forEach(function(item){
            //console.log(item)
            var a = moment(item);
            var start = a.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            var b = a.add(30, 'days');
            var end = b.format('YYYY-MM-DD')


            console.log("procesing search between date : ",start , " and last date: ", end)
            letrado.forEach((value, key) => {
                //console.log("1-key =>", key, "1-value =>", value.compra_fecha_oper);
                let polo = moment(value.compra_fecha_oper).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

                var tonto = moment(polo).isBetween(String(start), String(end) ); // true
                if ( tonto = true ){
                    console.log(key, " Value Date: ",value.compra_fecha_oper ,"Has result: ",  tonto)

                }

            });

          });
```

The result is a very long list like this:

[image]

But if you try this like concept:

```
      var isbetween = moment('2015-05-15').isBetween('2015-05-01', '2015-05-31');
      console.log("valor de isbetwen",isbetween )
```

Is working.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `if ( tonto = true ){` you mean `if ( tonto == true ){` or `if ( tonto === true ){` ... since `if ( tonto = true ){` is ALWAYS true as you assigned it to be true (= is assignment, not equality check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the isssue,

```
if ( tonto = true ){
```

This should be triple equal to

```
if ( tonto === true ){ 
/* or simply */ 
if ( tonto ){
```

Comment: Thank you, I had not noticed